# error when trying to read from excel in vb

Tags: vb.net, excel

I get this exception "could not find installable isam" when trying to read from an excel file in vb. I tried google and the most I get refers to a problem with my connection but I don't know how to fix that. Here is my connection string

```
Dim MyConnection As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
MyConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection _
        ("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.Oledb.4.0; Data Source='" & Application.StartupPath & "\kk.xls'; Extended Properties=Excel 9.0;")
```

Comment: I'm not sure this will fix it but try without the single-quotes and change to `Extended Properties=Excel 8.0.`

Comment: Thank you so much @Doug Glancy. I did exactly what you said and it is working fine now. Why not make it an answer so I can tick it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it without the single-quotes, and change to `Extended Properties=Excel 8.0`.

Comment: As a side note if you have Excel 2010 the version is 14.0